# Map not updating as expected

Tags: c++

I am trying to update a map but it is empty after making the changes.

```
typedef string Location;
typedef string Person;
typedef vector<string> Objects;

// this map is not behaving right
map<Location, map<Person, Objects>> totalmap;

// Add stuff to map
auto cityMap = totalmap["city"];
cityMap["Ed"] = Objects();
cityMap["Ed"].push_back("toothbrush");

// Check map
cityMap.size() // 1 (as expected)
totalmap["city"]["Ed"].size(); // 0 (where did it go?)
```

Why does `cityMap` show the changes but `totalmap` does not?

Comment: What was wrong with this question? How can I improve my question for next time?

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: There is no need for those `typedefs`.  They only obscure the rest of the code.

Comment: The `"Ed"` and `"ed"` inconsistency might be the answer to this problem

Comment: Sorry that was typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line of code:

```
auto cityMap = totalmap["city"];
```

`cityMap` is a **copy** of the value from that map key. Any changes made to `cityMap` are not reflected in your `totalmap` container.

One way to fix this is to make `cityMap` a **reference** to the map element.

```
auto& cityMap = totalmap["city"];
```

Note the ampersand.